# How to control Brightness

Tags: 12.04, brightness, acer

I didn't install anything myself, but only Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an Acer 4741g.

I use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> to change the brightness, but failed.

How can I control the brightness levels?

Comment: I may have a guide in hebrew with the sources of it. you need? or you got a solution?
Here: http://www.fxp.co.il/showthread.php?t=10255235&p=94282824#post94282824 Try using Google to translate all the page. Or, try the sorce at the end og tne manual.

Comment: Nothing worked software and settings-wise for me. Installing a different driver for the graphics did the trick. Go to software center, install "additional drivers" if you don't see a "additional drivers" tab already visible in system settings / software sources.

Comment: For followers, this is an "intel" gpu, not nvidia at all...

Answer (score 40):

Try this:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Then type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. It will ask for your password. Type it in.
3. Around the 11th line, there will be something like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`. Change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
4. Save the file by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Then run `sudo update-grub` in the terminal.
5. Reboot and see if backlight adjustment works. If not, undo the changes you did above, by invoking the text editor as in steps 1 and 2.

Hope it helps.

Works for Acer Aspire v3-571,Acer Aspire v3 571g,Hewlett Packard Bell EasyNote TS,Acer Aspire 4755G,Acer Aspire 5750-6866, Acer Aspire 5739, Lenovo T540p

Comment: To richy: i tried just ago it still didn't work. and if i press Fn+"left" , it will turn from the full to half . i press again, it will turn empty. it changes but the brightness doesn't change. and if i change it (also it won't work), but the next time, the brightness will be different from this time.....

Comment: @homelesser what do you mean when you say that brightness will be different from this time? You mean after a reboot, or something else? And another thing, did you update your system after installing ubuntu? if not, try updating it as well.

Comment: Thank you! I have a Packard Bell EasyNote TS, and the backlight was stuck at full everytime I was using Ubuntu. Did exactly what you said up there, rebooted, and boom, adjustable backlight. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this on my Aspire 4755G and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: works perfectly with full control on Acer Aspire V3-571G

Comment: It works for Acer Aspire One 756-1007Ckk

Comment: If this doesn't work, try `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=legacy"`, it worked on my Acer Aspire V5-471PG

Comment: also works on Acer TravelMat 8473. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't use to work for my Acer V3-571g (earlier distributions of Ubuntu/Xubuntu/Mint), but now, on Xubuntu 14.04 it's working great. Thank you.

Comment: I can also confirm this works on a Gateway NE56R. I also know that this bug will be fixed in Ubuntu 14.10 so we won't have to do this anymore! I should know. I used to be a Utopic beta tester. It was too unstable for me so I had to go back to trusty and use this work around of yours.

Comment: Worked perfectly on my ACER Travelmate P643-M with Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks, man!

Comment: A linked Q says to add both `acpi_osi=Linux` and `acpi_backlight=vendor`, as does one of the other answers here, but in a different line. Not sure if that's important/significant.

Comment: Works on my Acer 3820TG with:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

Comment: Also for Lenovo Ideapad P500, with Kubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 13):

*OP reported in [Revisions 2 & 3 of the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/240155/revisions) that the following worked for him.*

> I figured it out from different sites, it fixes backlight.
>
> Run the following command in Terminal:
>
> ```
> gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> then change
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
> ```
>
> then save and run:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> and then restart the system for changes to take effect.

Comment: It worked for me, on Acer Aspire One 756-1007Ckk, but only after a restart.

Comment: acer aspire e1-570g on Lubuntu worked too!

Answer (score 13):

## Ubuntu 14.04 (13.10+) with intel graphics

### How to check if graphics card is intel

First, check if your graphics card is intel. You can check it from **System Settings->Details->Graphics** or with following command:

```
ls /sys/class/backlight
```

You should see something like:

```
ideapad  intel_backlight
```

### Fix backlight

Make sure `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` exists. If it doesn't, make it yourself and add the following:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

**Logout and Login.** Done.

Thanks to [Abhishek](http://itsfoss.com/author/Abhishek/)

Reposted a solution that worked for me http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

Comment: Worked for Acer Aspire 3820T. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked for Acer Aspire 5334 with intel graphics.

Answer (score 7):

[Like in richy's, but] I use `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`

(I'm on an Aspire 5750-6866.)  It works fine, same control levels I had in Windows.

My brightness used to be stuck at max before I discovered this.

(Although brightness levels still reset after a restart/hibernate/shutdown)

Comment: I'm also on an Aspire 5750.  richy's solution had no effect, but this ended up working!  Finally! My eye's we're starting to melt.

Answer (score 2):

I found out a solution that worked with my laptop:

add this to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo 2 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I have a Travelmate P633-V and I did this code to fix it.

After installing the scripts my FN-Left and FN-Right are working fine.

The script should work with all intel devices that exposes 
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight

https://github.com/codingtony/acer-brightness-linux-acpi

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem when i upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04.
enter this in terminal
code:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Check for these lines GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and change it as the below and save it.

After the update the grub

code:  `sudo update-grub`

Code:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
`**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor"**`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Most simple and fast way to do this....
Use this command

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5
```

Set the value in between 0 to 1 like in this case it is 0.5
This works for me 
Try this !!!

Comment: This does change the brightness, but only by means of software, not hardware (i.e.: the level of backlight of laptops doesn't change, only the brightness of the colors)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst trying xbacklight didn't work for me because I'm using NVIDIA drivers, [Light](https://github.com/haikarainen/light) did the job pretty well for me.

After installing:

- Increase backlight brightness by 5 percent

  ```
  light -A 5
  ```
- Decrease backlight brightness by 5 percent

  ```
  light -U 5
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then change this line: 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`
Then in a terminal type `sudo update-grub`
Reboot and see if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

(Defunct) solution for Ubuntu **12.04.1**:

Use **Add Drivers** / **Additional Drivers** to load **Cedar Trail drm driver** (closed source).

---

For Ubuntu **12.04.2** (and fully updated **12.04**) this issue is resolved by more recent updates. *It does **not** require the proprietary driver.*

If you have just done a fresh install of **12.04.2**, then you need to update (and re-start) to fix this.

At terminal, type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

---

**Update:** (28-Apr-2013)

Repeated steps, with fresh install. This did **not** fix problem.

*While the brightness is fixed, any dimness/brightness adjustment (using function keys) does not seem work after this fix ..*

***Ongoing ...***

Answer (score 0):

### Same solution as one-liner

For this solution, no `nano` knowledge is required. As such, it may also come handy for multi-machine installation scripts.

```
sudo sed -i 's|^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"|GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"|' /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub
```

For the faint of heart, the above command edits the file `/etc/default/grub` to replace the appropriate line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

After editing, a `sudo update-grub` should be issued for the changes to take effect.

Comment: We should not encourage users to run commands like this. Especially if they cannot even work with nano. This is also not useful to more technical users, because it "obfuscates" what is really going on, and it will not work if you have other non-standard grub parameters.

Comment: @Galgalesh _"Treat all users with respect."_ You should urgently read [The impact of the Linux philosophy](http://opensource.com/business/14/12/linux-philosophy). _"The entire Unix philosophy revolves around the idea that the user knows what he or she is doing." "Unix was not designed to stop its users from doing stupid things, as that would also stop them from doing clever things."_

Comment: If I phrased my comment disrespectfully, I'm sorry for that. English is a second language to me, I do not mean to be disrespectful.

There is a big difference between permitting people to do stupid things and encouraging people to do stupid things. Linux still allows people to wget a random script from the internet and run it. That does not mean we should post it as a solution.

Your answer is dangerous, does not educate the user, and is not future-proof. No matter what the Linux philosophy might be, this is not a good askubuntu answer.

Comment: Firstly, the above command does *not* load any script from the internet; it does *exactly* the same as other solutions mentioned here. Secondly, this answer *is* educational as it shows how a system administrator would roll out this solution to numerous machines. It saves time and avoids any typing mistakes. Again, do not make any assumptions. Many people here run more than just a single instance of Ubuntu on a single machine. System administrators also come to SE to look for answers. Do not put a limit on yourself or others!

Comment: This is an excellent method, once the **correct** settings have been identified. It would allow a non-technical user to load the required settings. *However, it may not be the correct solution for any given user.*

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem as well. My notebook is an Acer Aspire E1-522. I could solve the brightness issue by changing from the X.Org X server to the proprietary AMD video driver.

To do so, go to **Software & Updates** and then go to the tab **Additional Drivers**. There you can probably find the proprietary driver. Select it and click **Apply Changes**. You will need to reboot you computer in order to know if it really helped.

Answer (score 0):

On Acer Aspire 4740 after installing Ubuntu 18.04, Screen brightness would not change.
Tried every thing above, did not help.

Added `blacklist acer-wmi` to */etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf* and rebooted

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> shortcut started working.

Reference:
https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2172282.html

Comment: Added the following in /etc/default/grub 

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"