# Cannot adjust brightness on my  Packard Bell EasyNote TS11HR-127GE laptop

Tags: nvidia, brightness, nvidia-optimus

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Packard Bell EasyNote TS11HR-127GE laptop and I cannot adjust the brightness. If I change the slider, the brightness is always at maximum. My laptop is using NVIDIA Optimus and has a integrated Intel HD 3000 and a NVIDIA GT540M graphic card. I already installed the newest Bumblebee version but this has also no effect.

Anyone an idea?

Here is the output of lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bbswitch               13396  0 
parport_pc             32866  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
bnep                   18281  2 
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bluetooth             180104  10 bnep,rfcomm
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32474  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   223867  1 
snd_hda_intel          33773  3 
snd_hda_codec         127706  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97188  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
arc4                   12529  2 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ath9k                 132390  0 
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
mac80211              506816  1 ath9k
uvcvideo               72627  0 
snd                    78855  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
psmouse                87692  0 
joydev                 17693  0 
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
serio_raw              13211  0 
ath9k_common           14053  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              411112  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    24067  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
cfg80211              205544  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
i915                  468651  3 
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 i915
drm                   242038  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
mei                    41616  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 i915
mxm_wmi                12979  0 
acer_wmi               28418  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 acer_wmi
video                  19596  1 i915
wmi                    19256  2 mxm_wmi,acer_wmi
mac_hid                13253  0 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usbhid                 47199  0 
hid                    99559  1 usbhid
tg3                   152032  0 
sdhci_pci              18826  0 
sdhci                  33205  1 sdhci_pci
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally this worked for me.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

([source](http://livinginjava.blogspot.de/2010/11/ubuntu-1010-brightness-problem-in-acer.html))

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the brightness with the button on you laptop, usually a Fx key. I am assuming you have tried to adjust with the software 'slider' but I'd try again after testing the hardware button.

If this does not work consider installing proprietary drivers.

Comment: I already tried using my Fn keys but this is also not working. I think I am using Bumblebee using the proprietary driver ( related to the installation instructons from the bumblebee homepage http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu ).

Comment: Consider booting into BIOS and trying to set the brightness there?

Comment: In BIOS are no settings for brightness, I also already made a BIOS update!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Then type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. It will ask for your password. Type it in.
3. Around the 11th line, there will be something like:
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
   Change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
4. Save the file by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Then run `sudo update-grub` in the terminal.
5. Reboot and see if backlight adjustment works. If not, undo the changes you did above, by invoking the text editor as in steps 1 and 2.

Hope it helps.
Credit to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/128471/25798]).

Answer (score 0):

### Same solution as one-liner

For this solution no `nano` knowledge is required. It is also handy for multi-machine installation scripts. This was tested on a Packard Bell Easynote TE11HC with Intel graphics.

```
sudo sed -i 's|^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"|GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"|' /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub
```