# adjust the brightness in 13.04

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, brightness

I have a dual graphics card: intel 4000 and nvidia 630m...

I installed bumblebee and intel drivers from their website. I thought the brightness problem will be solved by installing these drivers.

But, brightness works only for two steps: that is, dim, medium, high... But, it doesn't increase step wise. Can you please help me sort this problem?

I'm a newbie to ubuntu and this is my first trial. So, please give me a detailed guide... Thank you :)

EDIT: My model is HP DV6 7040tx. [My Laptop Model](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03354579&cc=in&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_r1002_inen_c-001_title_r0002)

Comment: update your laptop model

Comment: added the laptop model!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out in this thread: [How to control Brightness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128463/how-to-control-brightness)

Just to keep it straight

> Run the following command in Terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> then change
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
> ```
>
> then save and run:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> and then restart the system for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings --> Brightness & Lock. Here you can manually set your brightness by sliding the bar to the left/right. Hope this helps!

Comment: that bar as i mentioned, DOESN'T CHANGE. Only 3 step works not more .

Comment: Ow I thought you used keyboard buttons for changing the brightness and those only allowed the 3 steps. No idea then I'm pretty new to Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it.

I changed `acpi_osi=Linux` to `acpi_osi=Linux backlight=vendor`, then ran:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

A reboot and the sensitivity is fixed.

It seems all Intel/Nvidia dual graphics card are affected by this.

Answer (score 0):

Look for nvidia panel in dash, open it up and make the changes there.