# Brightness Problem

Tags: laptop, brightness, acer

Hello there Linux user I am a new user and I don't know how to turn down my brightness of my laptop when I change it with the keys it show on the screen going down but the screen is not dimming I don't know why and I will really like to know why since i want to use this a long time please help my laptop type
is :Acer Asphire-V5-561PG 6819

Version is there any fix please help

Comment: see here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/128463/how-to-control-brightness

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the current answer, get the output name of your screen by running:

```
xrandr --current
```

You can determine if the screen is running if it has 'connected' next to it. For me, the display was called

```
eDP1
```

So, I can change the brightness by runnning

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 0.5
```

And replacing 0.5 with any value

Comment: Although `xrandr --current` *includes* the desired information, it is quite more extensive then just the screen name. You might want to mention that it is the name before "connected"

Answer (score -1):

Open the terminal. Type:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5
```

You can change 0.5 to any value. 0 will make the screen black and greater value than 0.5 will make the screen brighter.