# Brightness control turns off my monitor

Tags: 14.04, unity, laptop, brightness

When I press the keyboard combination to lower my brightness i.e. Fn+F2 my screen turn off and to turn it on I have to press brightness low and then brightness high button one after another.

Can anyone tell me whats going on and how to solve it.

Comment: Which is your hardware? Try the solution here http://askubuntu.com/questions/128463/how-to-control-brightness or here http://askubuntu.com/questions/28848/what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi-osi-linux-do

Answer (score 0):

I assuming your changing the levels so much that your monitor is not detecting an input. Try putting your levels to a "medium" level and the change the brightness setting on the monitor instead. Hope this helps!

Comment: how do I do that and remember my monitor has no brightness control, it's a laptop

Comment: Ok sorry I assumed it was a desktop,

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is keeping the brightness at a medium level. Otherwise I would contact support.