# Cannot install Intel HD Graphic drivers on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics

Im kinda new to Ubuntu. 
Well I have a problem here. My laptop has Intel HD Graphic but after I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I cannot control my brightness. When I go in Setting I notice my OS did not reconize the "Intel HD Graphic". I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS but they dont even boot up only a black screen. So is there any solution for this? I wanna use Ubuntu 12.04 so bad. If there is plz give me. I really love Ubuntu this is very impotant for me. 
(Sorry if bad english tho)

Comment: There are multiple things you can try here [https://askubuntu.com/questions/128463/how-to-control-brightness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128463/how-to-control-brightness)

Comment: What hardware do you have? (ie: CPU, GPU, etc.)